# What are stable Magento versions from 1.4.1.1?

Tags: upgrade

I'm currently using Magento 1.4.1.1. I'm thinking of upgrading it. 
I have never conducted this kind of operation.

What are the stable and compatible Magento versions from 1.4.1.1 ?
Do you know any best practices to succeed an upgrade ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While backups with Magento can be straightforward there are many things to consider that can cause potential complications. Here are just a few things to consider:

Do you have any extensions installed (check app/code/community/ and app/code/local/) and will they be compatible with the new version you are upgrading to?

Do you have any modified core files? 
This one is HUGE. I have seen it many times when a lazy / sloppy developer modifies core Magento files. When this happens you will almost always have issues when upgrading because those changes might be lost.

To check for this you need to obtain a FRESH copy of the CURRENT version you are using and run a "diff". 
There are a few desktop programs that can do this or you can easily do it via the command line using the "diff" command. You want to run this and compare the files for your current version against the same FRESH version and compare app/code/core/ on both.

If any files differ you will either need to re-implement those changes in the upgraded version (not recommended) or properly move those changes into the app/code/local/ folder (recommended).

Create a testing plan. Sometimes you might have issues but they're not glaring and obvious. Create a good plan for in-depth testing of the site to be sure you can discover any problems if they occur.

Always do an upgrade on a dev machine. Chances are you'll have issues that you'll need to work through. Do it on dev first and document the fixes / changes you have to do. After you get it all working then you should have a game plan to do it for your live site.